# Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value & main storyboard won't show up

Tags: swift, xcode

```
@IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSKView!
var selectedImage: ImageInformation?

let images = ["VeganMilk": ImageInformation(name: "VeganMilk", description: "Hi", image: UIImage(named: "VeganMilk")!)]
```

Whenever I launch my app, it says:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

For let images ... and then the app only stays on the launch screen. What can I do to fix this error and move on to the `ARSKView`?

Comment: Check the image name spelling and confirm if it is in your XCAssets. Since the image is the only thing you are forcefully unwrapping, it is the only thing that can cause that crash.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check inside your `Assets` if you actually have an image named `"VeganMilk"`. To avoid crash you can do nil coalescing like this:

```swift
let images = ["VeganMilk": ImageInformation(name: "VeganMilk", description: "Hi", image: UIImage(named: "VeganMilk") ?? UIImage())
```

Comment: Yeah VeganMilk is in a folder that's in my asset. Should I put the name of the folder or name of the image?

Comment: You should give the image name.

Comment: It worked thanks, but now when it moves from the launch screen to the main storyboard a grey screen pops up. I have the ARSKView (AR Camera) with a present modally segue in the main storyboard. How do I get the camera to work and to recognise the image?

Comment: @Tega Welcome, if you found the answer helpful upvote and mark as correct when it allows you.

Comment: @Tega I'm not sure about AR Camera you might want to do some research or ask another question regarding that.